# Rearranging License Plate characters based on country

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am doing a License/Number plate recognition project and I'm on the stage of completion but there is a small problem, I have successfully recognized the characters, consider the below example:
[image]

This is an input image, I got the prediction as `2791 2g rj14`

As you can, the ocr did a great job but the arrangement is destroyed (DESTROYING the whole purpose). **Sometimes it does outputs in the correct sequence but sometimes it does not**, so when it does not output in the correct sequence I'm trying to develop an algorithm which will take the predicted `num_plate` string as input and rearrange it on the basis of my country (India).

Below are some images which tell us about the format of Indian Number/License Plate.

[image]

Also, I have collected all the states but for right now, I just want to do for only the 3 states which are: Delhi (DL), Haryana (HR), UttarPradesh (UP). More info : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Regional_Transport_Office_districts_in_India

```
total_states_list = [
    'AN','AP','AR','AS','BR','CG','CH','DD','DL','DN','GA','GJ','HR','HP','JH','JK','KA','KL',
    'LD','MH','ML','MN','MP','MZ','NL','OD','PB','PY','RJ','SK','TN','TR','TS','UK','UP','WB'
]

district_codes = {
    'DL': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'],
    'HR': [01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
            40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,
            71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99
    ]
}
```

So, I have been trying but cannot come up with an algorithm which rearranges the sequence in the required sequence if it is not. Any help would be really appreciated.

### Details about OCR

Using `keras-ocr`, I'm getting the following output for the input image:
[image]

```
[
  ('hrlz',  array([[ 68.343796,  42.088367],
                   [196.68803 ,  26.907867],
                   [203.00832 ,  80.343094],
                   [ 74.66408 ,  95.5236  ]], dtype=float32)), 
  ('c1044', array([[ 50.215836, 113.09602 ],
                   [217.72466 ,  92.58473 ],
                   [224.3968  , 147.07387 ],
                   [ 56.887985, 167.58516 ]], dtype=float32))
]
```

source: https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/using_pretrained_models.html

Inside the `keras_ocr.tools.drawAnnotations` they are I think getting the predictions boxes. So I located this file and found the implementation of `drawAnnotations` function and here it is:

```
def drawAnnotations(image, predictions, ax=None):
  if ax is None:
        _, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(drawBoxes(image=image, boxes=predictions, boxes_format='predictions'))
    predictions = sorted(predictions, key=lambda p: p[1][:, 1].min())
    left = []
    right = []
    for word, box in predictions:
        if box[:, 0].min() < image.shape[1] / 2:
            left.append((word, box))
        else:
            right.append((word, box))
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([])
    for side, group in zip(['left', 'right'], [left, right]):
        for index, (text, box) in enumerate(group):
            y = 1 - (index / len(group))
            xy = box[0] / np.array([image.shape[1], image.shape[0]])
            xy[1] = 1 - xy[1]
            ax.annotate(s=text,
                        xy=xy,
                        xytext=(-0.05 if side == 'left' else 1.05, y),
                        xycoords='axes fraction',
                        arrowprops={
                            'arrowstyle': '->',
                            'color': 'r'
                        },
                        color='r',
                        fontsize=14,
                        horizontalalignment='right' if side == 'left' else 'left')
    return ax
```

How should I go about and get the (x,y,w,h) and then somehow sort/print according to y/x of number_plate bbox?

**EDIT - 2**

I managed to get the bounding box of characters as you can see in the image below:

[image]

using the function `cv2.polylines(box)`, where `box` are the same coordinates where I have pasted the output earlier. Now how can I print them in a sequence like, left to right... using the y/x as suggested by people in the comments.

Comment: Is there any pattern to how these sequences get re-arranged?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, see i have attached an image in which, the state code comes first (2 digits), then district code `district_codes` (sometimes 1 or 2 digits), then a unique combination...

Comment: What is the format in which you get the chunks? Is it a space separated, single string? A list of strings?

Comment: @trincot it is a single string, eg: `detected_num_plate = '27912grj14'`

Comment: OK, but then you cannot know whether the real licence plate was maybe `rj1214279g`. Or do you have more rules?

Comment: @trincot not many but yeah, the characters in number plate cannot be more or less than 10. Also, first two digits are always from my `total_states_list` and next 2 digit from `district_codes`.

Comment: Yes, I had a mistake in my comment. Updated. Any reason why it could not be `rj1214279g`, or `rj272g1491` Without more rules, it seems there are multitudes of outcomes possible.

Comment: @dev1ce: What you describe is the *desired* sequence; I asked about any kind of pattern to how it gets re-arranged (the idea being that, if such a pattern exists, it suggests what to do to un-re-arrange it).

Comment: @trincot yes, it could not be because after 2 digit state code `rj` 2 digit district code should come... See, what I'm thinking that, the last 4 characters are always going to be digits and not alphabets, the first 2 are always going to be 2 digits from the `total_states_list`, for the remaining, we need to develop something...

Comment: You'll need the bounding boxes for the results, then ORDER BY Y,X and concatenate the strings the OCR found in the bounding box.

Comment: @Iñigo sounds good, you mean, after getting the license plate bboxes (x,y,w,h) based on the y,x , I keep recognizing digit by digit? And what about those plates which are of 2 lines just like the 1st image of the question...

Comment: But still there are multitude of possibilities. Are any of these violating a rule `rj12g14279`, `rj112g2794`, `rj212g7914`?

Comment: @trincot I am not really sure because there is a lot of things behind creating a number plate... Yes you're right, there are multitude of possibilities..., So there isn't anything we could do?

Comment: No, unless you have more restrictive rules. As far as I understand there is no restriction as to how much the OCR may shuffle the characters it has read. So that means you must consider every permutation of the characters that still fits all the rules. Even if you know that the last 4 positions are always numeric, there seems no restriction to have to consider every possible permutation of the digits you have.

Comment: You could do more if the OCR would return to you the *coordinates* of where it found each character.

Comment: @trincot i used the `keras-ocr` pre-trained model, it returns an array of coordinates i think, i need to check that. Will update you If i got something.

Comment: @trincot Edited the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: So if you can get these box coordinates (can you?), then rotate them all around a single point such that the boxes are approximately aligned with the X-axis, and then determine the "lines" the texts are on (grouping by Y). Then order by X. However, I see in your last example the OCR wrongly identified "47" as "lz". That would be a problem.

Comment: @trincot do you have a code example? because that will help a lot, it's okay if you can't. Yes, it wrongly identified that part, I tried fine-tuning it but it was not learning, the val_loss was not decreasing at all. Steps I followed to fine-tune: https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/fine_tuning_recognizer.html

Comment: @trincot Hi, I have updated the question, I managed to draw bboxes using the coordinates in the question above. Now how can I proceed..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the coordinates of each identified text box, then:

- Rotate the coordinates so the boxes are parallel with the X-axis
- Scale the Y-coordinates so they can be rounded to integers, so that boxes that are side-by-side will get the same integer Y-coordinate (like a line number)
- Sort the data by Y, then X coordinate
- Extract the texts in that order

Here is an example of such sequence:

```
data = [
  ('hrlz', [[ 68.343796,  42.088367],
            [196.68803 ,  26.907867],
            [203.00832 ,  80.343094],
            [ 74.66408 ,  95.5236  ]]), 
  ('c1044',[[ 50.215836, 113.09602 ],
            [217.72466 ,  92.58473 ],
            [224.3968  , 147.07387 ],
            [ 56.887985, 167.58516 ]])
]

# rotate data to align with X-axis
a, b = data[0][1][:2]
dist = ((b[1] - a[1]) ** 2 + (b[0] - a[0]) ** 2) ** 0.5
sin = (b[1] - a[1]) / dist
cos = (b[0] - a[0]) / dist
data = [
    (text, [(x * cos + y * sin, y * cos - x * sin) for x, y in box]) for text, box in data
]

# scale Y coordinate to integers
a, b = data[0][1][1:3]
height = b[1] - a[1]
data = [
    (round(box[0][1] / height), box[0][0], text) 
        for text, box in data
]

# sort by Y, then X
data.sort()

# Get text in the right order
print("".join(text for _, _, text in data))
```

This assumes that the points of the boxes are given in the following clockwise order:

```
top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left
```